# Sitecore XDb aggregation Exception

Tags: xdb, cosmos-db

We are using Sitecore 8.2.7 and developing XDB capabalties with Cosmos(we are fully aware that Cosmos is not officaly supported) so far we are able to see analytics data in Cosmos but we are able to see data in Sitecore Analytics Dashboard. Any inputs about this exception

ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/automationAggregator
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB
 Sitecore.Analytics.RangeScheduler.MongoDbRangeMap2.TryLockRange(WorkerHandle worker, DateTime leaseExpiration, RangeHandle& range)
Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.TryLockRange(WorkScheduler`1& context)
Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.GetNextRange(WorkScheduler`1& context)
Sitecore.Analytics.Core.RangeScheduler.RangeMapWorkScheduler2`1.TryGetNext(TKey& item)
   Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.AutomationWorkDispatcher.TryGetNext(AutomationWorkItem& workItem)
    Sitecore.Analytics.Automation.Aggregation.Data.Processing.AggregatorAgent.Execute()
 Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()